# Ember.js router with variable

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I've just started using Ember.js and have got stuck at the first hurdle!

My URL structure is `/username/action`, so for example `/matt/feed` (or just `/matt` with a default view).

But, although I've managed to get a hardcoded username value to output something, I don't know how to have the username part of the URL be a variable which I can then do things with.

The code I'm using to hardcode the username is below, haven't really got anywhere because I'm not really sure how to get Ember.js to understand my URLs!

```
'use strict';
window.App = Ember.Application.create();
App.Router.reopen({
    location:'history'
});
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('matt');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right from the documentation at http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts');
  this.resource('post', { path: '/post/:post_id' });
});
```

`:post_id` is the dynamic segment of the route.